# How can I detect when the Windows 7 start menu opens

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I have written a WPF application in C# which I would like to show every time the start menu is opened and hide again when the menu is closed. *I would prefer to do this without polling the state of the start menu.* So far I've tried listening to the SHELLHOOK messages but I'm not seeing anything useful there.

Comment: I'm not sure that application will get a lot of user appreciation! :)

Comment: I'm the user, I'll appreciate it! I've been forced to use Windows and I'd rather be on Gnome-shell.

Comment: If you're the only user then why would it matter if code does poll or doesn't?

Comment: I can't see how the number of users makes polling better. As far as I'm concerned, polling is always the last resort.

Comment: Instead of focusing on a possible tech level solution, what are you trying to *accomplish*?

Comment: @snemarch Have you used Gnome-Shell? It has a dashboard that encompasses both a launcher and an Exposé clone. What I have completed is an Exposé clone; I'd like it to open along with the start menu accomplishing something close to the Gnome-Shell dashboard.

Comment: Windows Key + Tab is close enough for me. You can click the window you want with the mouse as well.

Answer (score 2):

I Can't write you full code but here is the logic behind it,

1. First find the handle for the task bar using

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
   ```

   also pass `Shell_TrayWnd` as lpClassName
2. Activate the **Start** Menu by simulating click button.
3. Get the window handle of **Start Menu**
4. Use `GetWindowLong` function to check it is open or not.

Comment: Yes, this will work _if I poll_. I'd rather not poll so I'll update my question.

Comment: how would you use GetWindowLong in order to check if the Start Menu is open or not?