# Detect start menu open

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

How can I detect the user opening/closing the start menu in c#? Is there a way to do it?

Also, is it possible to detect opening/closing the search button?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120514/how-can-i-detect-when-the-windows-7-start-menu-opens) related post, but it does not fully describe a solution.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aed1fcd9-510a-467e-adef-7f94db0a95f6/detecting-windows-10-start-menu-is-the-active-window?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when the Windows start menu / start screen opens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085746/how-to-detect-when-the-windows-start-menu-start-screen-opens)

Comment: The answer to that question is "impossible". I'm not buying that.